# Is there a way to Capitalize the first letter of firstName and lastName and make it an Innitial in Javascript

Tags: javascript

// Add a method to the Person's prototype called "getInitials" that returns the first letter of their first and last name, both capitalized.

```js
function Person(firstName, lastName) {
  Person.prototype.getInitials = function() {
    let name = (firstName, lastName) => {
      return name.split(' ').map(word => word.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + word.substr(1, word.length)).join(' ');
    };
  }
}

/* Do not modify code below this line */
const johnDoe = new Person('john', 'doe');
console.log(johnDoe.getInitials(), '<-- should be "JD"');
```

Comment: You are returning inside a nested function, you are not returning anything from `getInitials` itself. Actually you aren't doing anything in `getInitials` except creating a new function expression

Comment: Set `firstName` and `lastName` as property of the instance (`this.firstName = firstName`). Define the prototype outside of the constructor function. Otherwise each `new` operator use will overwrite the previous method. Use `this.firstName` inside the `getInitials` method and return the string

Comment: remove this part of your code in front of getInitials

Comment: Just FYI, you can use CSS text-transform: capitalize to capitalize the first letter of words

Comment: @ControlAltDel looking at *"Do not modify code below this line*", it looks like an online assignment rather than something to do with displaying it on a page

Comment: Thank you all. My confusion always comes from the "learning class assignment" when the function is to be modified rather than writing the code from the scratch and this is giving me a real concern cus it always messed up what I already learnt and know and I'm scare in case when I'm done to get a job and facing interview questions like this. Anything I can do to have the real understanding of this logical part....Thanks once again to everyone that provide a solution on this code

Answer (score 3):

1. Do not set the prototype inside `Person`'s constructor

Every time you instantiate a `Person` you will modify the prototype of `Person` which is not what you want to do.
Set it once (outside of `Person`) is enough.

2. You don't need to substring everything, just keep the first letter

```js
function Person(firstName, lastName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
}
Person.prototype.getInitials = function() {
  return `"${(this.firstName[0]+this.lastName[0]).toUpperCase()}"`;
}
  
/* Do not modify code below this line */
const johnDoe = new Person('john', 'doe');
console.log(johnDoe.getInitials(), '<-- should be "JD"');
```

Comment: Thank you all. My confusion always comes from the "learning class assignment" when the function is to be modified rather than writing the code from the scratch and this is giving me a real concern cus it always messed up what I already learnt and know and I'm scare in case when I'm done to get a job and facing interview questions like this. Anything I can do to have the real understanding of this logical part....Thanks once again to everyone that provide a solution on this code

Comment: How do I make the output has a string Quote => "JD"

Comment: @Dr3 use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):  `"${johnDoe.getInitials()}"` or concatenation... ```'"'+johnDoe.getInitials()+'"'```

Comment: That is not what I meant. String literal work with console.log I mean the output of the code snippet if you run it the output is JD suppose to be "JD"JD <-- should be "JD"

Comment: I insist. I have not talked about string litteral but template strings. I even gave you the alternative with string concatenation!!! test it!

Comment: I have updated the code. I don't think you should go further before training yourself with template strings as you may understand them but not be able to use them.

Comment: Thank you. I got it perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

Can't it be like this below, isn't it easier?

You don't need to define prototype inside the `Person`, but can use `this`.
Also you can just get the first character by index position `[0]`, without splits or substrings.

```js
function Person(firstName, lastName) {
  this.getInitials = function() {
    return firstName[0].toUpperCase() + lastName[0].toUpperCase()
  };
}

const johnDoe = new Person('john', 'doe');
console.log(johnDoe.getInitials());

const maryAnn = new Person('mary', 'ann');
console.log(maryAnn.getInitials());
```

Of course, I would recommend some verification to see if `firstName` and `lastName` aren't null/undefined before get its first character.

If you want to define prototype, then do it outside of `Person`

```
function Person(f,n){...};
Person.prototype.getInitials = function(){...}
```

Comment: Thank you all. My confusion always comes from the "learning class assignment" when the function is to be modified rather than writing the code from the scratch and this is giving me a real concern cus it always messed up what I already learnt and know and I'm scare in case when I'm done to get a job and facing interview questions like this. Anything I can do to have the real understanding of this logical part....Thanks once again to everyone that provide a solution on this code

Comment: How do I make  the return have a quote ??

Answer (score 0):

```js
var firstName ="jhon";
var lastName = "doe";

getInitials= function(fname,lname){
return fname[0].toUpperCase()+' '+lname[0].toUpperCase();
}

console.log(getInitials(firstName,lastName));
```

Comment: Thank you all. My confusion always comes from the "learning class assignment" when the function is to be modified rather than writing the code from the scratch and this is giving me a real concern cus it always messed up what I already learnt and know and I'm scare in case when I'm done to get a job and facing interview questions like this. Anything I can do to have the real understanding of this logical part....Thanks once again to everyone that provide a solution on this code

Answer (score 0):

YOu can do something like using classes

```js
class Person {
  constructor (firstName, lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }
  
  getInitials () {
    return this.firstName[0].toUpperCase() + this.lastName[0].toUpperCase();
  }
}


const person = new Person('jon', 'doe');

console.log(person.getInitials());
```

Comment: Thank you all. My confusion always comes from the "learning class assignment" when the function is to be modified rather than writing the code from the scratch and this is giving me a real concern cus it always messed up what I already learnt and know and I'm scare in case when I'm done to get a job and facing interview questions like this. Anything I can do to have the real understanding of this logical part....Thanks once again to everyone that provide a solution on this code

Comment: How do I make  it return with a quote? 'JD'

Comment: @Dr3 return \`'${this.firstName[0].toUpperCase()}${this.lastName[0].toUpperCase()}'\`

Answer (score 0):

### Answer:

To do what you're trying to do we can hardcode `getInitials` as a method on our Person Constructor:

```
// Construct Object
function Person(firstName, lastName) {
  return Object.assign(this, { firstName, lastName });
}

// adjust Constructor Prototype
Person.prototype.getInitials = function() {
         return `${this.firstName[0]} ${this.lastName[0]}`.toUpperCase();
}
```

```js
// Construct Object
function Person(firstName, lastName) {
  return Object.assign(this, { firstName, lastName });
}

// adjust Constructor Prototype
Person.prototype.getInitials = function() {
         return `${this.firstName[0]} ${this.lastName[0]}`.toUpperCase();
}

/* Do not modify code below this line */
const johnDoe = new Person('john', 'doe');
console.log( johnDoe.getInitials() )
```

---

### Alternatives:

In cases like this it's often beneficial to keep in line the idea that `methods` are **actions** instead of **property seeking**.

For instance, instead of equipping your constructed Object with something like `Person.getInitials` it would make more sense, logically, to be able to simply write `Person.initials`.

In keeping with that we can choose to hardcode the property:

```
function Person(firstName, lastName) {
  return Object.assign(this, {
    firstName,
    lastName,
    initials: `${firstName[0]} ${lastName[0]}`.toUpperCase()
  })
}
```

```js
function Person(firstName, lastName) {
  return Object.assign(this, {
    firstName,
    lastName,
    initials: `${firstName[0]} ${lastName[0]}`.toUpperCase()
  })
}


/* Do not modify code below this line */
const johnDoe = new Person('john', 'doe');
console.log(johnDoe.initials)
```

Or, if we're looking to be more clear with our code ( **always a good thing** ), we could do the following utilizing an accessor property ( otherwise known as `getters` and/or `setters` ):

```
function Person(firstName, lastName) {

  // define properties
  Object.defineProperties(this, {
    firstName: {
      value: firstName
    },
    lastName: {
      value: lastName
    },
    initials: {
      get: function() {
        return `${firstName[0]} ${lastName[0]}`.toUpperCase();
      }
    }
  });

}
```

```js
function Person(firstName, lastName) {
  
  // define properties
  Object.defineProperties(this, {
    firstName: {
      value: firstName
    },
    lastName: {
      value: lastName
    },
    initials: {
      get: function() {
        return `${firstName[0]} ${lastName[0]}`.toUpperCase();
      }
    }
  });
  
}

/* Do not modify code below this line */
const johnDoe = new Person('john', 'doe');
console.log( johnDoe.initials )
```

---

### Aside:

An additional benefit of not extending the `prototype` unnecessarily is that you are able to prevent changes to these Constructed Objects by freezing them when they are created. This adds some peace-of-mind if, in the future, some other Developer tries to alter the Object on the fly instead of altering the Constructor properly. This also doubles as a, albeit flimsy, piece of extra security for your code.

```
function Person(firstName, lastName) {

  // define properties
  Object.defineProperties(this, {
    firstName: {
      value: firstName
    },
    lastName: {
      value: lastName
    },
    initials: {
      get: function() {
        return `${firstName[0]} ${lastName[0]}`.toUpperCase();
      }
    }
  });

  // prevent alteration
  Object.freeze(this);

}
```

```js
function Person(firstName, lastName) {

  // define properties
  Object.defineProperties(this, {
    firstName: {
      value: firstName
    },
    lastName: {
      value: lastName
    },
    initials: {
      get: function() {
        return `${firstName[0]} ${lastName[0]}`.toUpperCase();
      }
    }
  });

  // prevent alteration
  Object.freeze(this);

}

/* Do not modify code below this line */
const johnDoe = new Person('john', 'doe');
console.log(johnDoe.initials)

console.log("Attempting to change firstName to Zak...");
johnDoe.firstName = "Zak";

console.log("But firstName remains: " + johnDoe.firstName);
```

---

### Conclusion:

Though ultimately everything is entirely open to your circumstances and discretion, I hope this answer helps illuminate some of the different options you have to produce clearer and more efficient code!

**Happy Coding!**

Comment: Thank you all. My confusion always comes from the class assignment when the function is to be modified rather than writing the code from the scratch and this is giving me a real concern cus it always messed up what I already learnt and know and I'm scare in case when I'm done to get a job and facing interview questions like this. Anything I can do to have the real understand of this logical part....Thanks once again to everyone that provide a solution on this code.